# Orace SQL - Nested CASE statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to add a COD parameter to a function.  The COD is a number, either a 2, 4, or 6.  I need to convert a parameter unit1 into unit2 based on whatever the quantity is.

I only care about the last portion of the code, when the unit1 is a 'tablet' and the `cod = 4` and it is converting from 'tablet' to kg (for unit2). I want the code to calculate by `WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.0000011` otherwise if it is anything else but c`od = 4`  then I want it to calculate by `WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.00025`.

How do I write the code below to get it to compile correctly?

I am getting a syntax error in Oracle.  Am I not nesting my CASE statements correctly.

```
create or replace FUNCTION  CONVERTUNITOFMEASURE_COD
 (COD NUMBER,
QUANTITY NUMBER,
UNIT1 VARCHAR2,
UNIT2 VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER IS
  IVALUE NUMBER;
  OUT_UOM NUMBER;
BEGIN

CASE UPPER(UNIT1)

WHEN 'KG' THEN
    CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
      WHEN 'LB' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY / 0.45359237;
      WHEN 'G' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY / 0.001;
      WHEN 'L' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY / 0.8;
      WHEN 'TABL' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY / 0.00025;
      WHEN 'GAL' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY / 2.64;
      WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
      ELSE NULL;
    END CASE;

WHEN 'G' THEN
    CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
      WHEN 'LB' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY  * 0.00220462262 ;
      WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.001;
      WHEN 'G' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
      ELSE NULL;
    END CASE;

WHEN 'LB' THEN
    CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
        WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.45359237;
        WHEN 'G' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 453.59237;
        WHEN 'LB' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
        ELSE NULL;
    END CASE;

WHEN 'L' THEN
     CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
         WHEN 'ML' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1000;
         WHEN 'GAL' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.264172052;
         WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.8;
         WHEN 'L' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
         ELSE NULL;
      END CASE;

WHEN 'ML' THEN
     CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
         WHEN 'L' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.001;
         WHEN 'GAL' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY / 3785.41178;
         WHEN 'ML' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
         ELSE NULL;
      END CASE;

WHEN 'GAL' THEN
     CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
         WHEN 'L' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 3.785411784;
         WHEN 'ML' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 3785.41178;
         WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 2.64;
         WHEN 'GAL' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
         ELSE NULL;
      END CASE;

WHEN 'TABL' THEN
             CASE WHEN (COD) = 4 THEN 
  CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
             WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.0000011;
         WHEN 'TABL' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
     ELSE NULL;
     END CASE;

     CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
         WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.00025;
         WHEN 'TABL' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
        ELSE NULL;
      END CASE;
ELSE NULL;
END CASE;
OUT_UOM := IVALUE ;
RETURN OUT_UOM;
END;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the final `end case`.

Answer (score 0):

If you indent the end section consintently you can see that you are missing an `END CASE;`:

```
WHEN 'TABL' THEN
     CASE WHEN (COD) = 4 THEN 
         CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
             WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.0000011;
             WHEN 'TABL' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
             ELSE NULL;
         END CASE;
         CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
             WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.00025;
             WHEN 'TABL' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
             ELSE NULL;
         END CASE;
         ELSE NULL;
     END CASE;

-- shoudld have another END CASE; here

OUT_UOM := IVALUE ;
RETURN OUT_UOM;
END;
```

Although the two nested case's in there seem to be wrong too; the second just overwrites the values set by the first - perhaps you are also missing an `ELSE` between those:

```
WHEN 'TABL' THEN
     CASE WHEN (COD) = 4 THEN 
         CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
             WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.0000011;
             WHEN 'TABL' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
             ELSE NULL;
         END CASE;
     ELSE
         CASE UPPER(UNIT2)
             WHEN 'KG' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 0.00025;
             WHEN 'TABL' THEN IVALUE := QUANTITY * 1;
             ELSE NULL;
         END CASE;
     END CASE;

END CASE;

OUT_UOM := IVALUE ;
RETURN OUT_UOM;
END;
```